# Can I delete original EC2 instance after creating an image out of it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I've setup a EC2 instance with EBS root. As part of the process, the system has created a snapshot of its EBS volume. My doubt is what happens when I remove the EC2 instance (and its EBS volume).

After deleting the EBS volume, will the snapshot still have the full copy of my system?
Will I be able to restore a copy of my system in future out of the AMI?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you create an AMI from an EC2 instance, you can terminate the instance and create a new one from the AMI.

If you have taken a snapshot of the EBS boot volume the instances is using, you will need to register it as an AMI before you can create a new instance.

If you take a snapshot of a volume, and then delete the original volume, you can recreate the volume from the snapshot even if the original volume is deleted.

Comment: One caveat: data on ephemeral (aka instance) storage will not be included in a snapshot, even if your boot volume is on EBS. You *can* add instance volumes to an AMI but they aren't included by default.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Amazon's default termination behaviors for EBS-backed instances:

> By default, the root device volume and the other Amazon EBS volumes attached when you launch an Amazon EBS-backed instance are automatically deleted when the instance terminates. For information about how to change this behavior when you launch an instance, see Changing the Root Device Volume to Persist.
>
> By default, any Amazon EBS volumes that you attach to a running instance are detached with their data intact when the instance terminates. You can attach a detached volume to any running instance.

If you create an AMI from your EBS-backed instance, a separate volume will be created when you launch a new instance based on that AMI with your data persisted from the time of the last snapshot of that volume.

[More info about Root Device Storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html)