# copy amazon resources from one account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two amazon aws account's and i want to move all `SQS` `EC2` `RDS` `S3` `CLOUDFRONT` `SECURITY GROUP'S` to the new account .

And i have `EC2` account id and account secret key in the `AMI IMAGE` for `AWS CLI` after moving to the new account how can i change all `EC2` account id and account secret key to new account?

What is the best and fast way to do so?

Thank You

Comment: I have the same issue but with a few more services like **SNS**, **ECS**, **Route 53** and **VPC** that I need to migrate duplicate to an entire new account.

With de DNS's it's not possible to copy once that depends on unique names, but with the other services I need to a easy way to do that, by services.

Could you help guys?

I've been reading about Amazon Organizations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of what you've mentioned is *configuration*. Some is content. Let's unroll it and go through each one. Generally, the answer is "no".

### SQS

Create a new SQS queue and point code/configuration at it. Alternatively, you can [enable cross-account delegation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-creatingrole-policyexamples.html) (though this doesn't change ownership).

### EC2

[Running instances cannot be moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310528/move-aws-ec2-instance-to-another-account). Either create new instances and reprovision them (with, say, ansible/salt/puppet/chef) or create an AMI of the EC2, [share the ami](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html), and relaunch.

### RDS

[RDS instances can't be copied. You will need to extract the data and transfer it to a new database instance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192609/can-rds-snapshots-be-transferred-across-aws-accounts)

### S3

Buckets cannot be moved between accounts. You can [copy data into a new bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518205/move-files-directly-from-one-s3-account-to-another) or [enable cross-account delegation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-creatingrole-policyexamples.html) (though this doesn't change ownership).

### CLOUDFRONT

Cloudfront cannot be moved. Creating this in a new account is very easy, though, since it's basically stateless (you don't need to worry about anything beyond setting it up).

### SECURITY GROUP'S

Security groups cannot be moved.

### Accounts and secrets

> And i have EC2 account id and account secret key in the AMI IMAGE for AWS CLI after moving to the new account how can i change all EC2 account id and account secret key to new account?

Use AWS IAM to generate correct user(s) with security keys. This involves using a new ID and key. If you are using IDs and keys you should be comfortable rotating them to reduce security risk.

The alternative is to use [IAM roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), which means you don't need to store or use explicit keys.

## The bottom line

Ultimately, you should be keeping most of this information in configuration management. This is almost trivial to do with [CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/), which describes an entire stack (EC2, cloudfront, security groups, databases) and can create them in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use [AWS Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/merge-aws-accounts/) to roll up your child account into the parent one, rather than trying to move everything by hand.